# VB How to target a specific table in an Access Database

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

```
Private Sub ButtonAddEmpSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonAddEmpSave.Click
        provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
        dataFile = "\localdatabase.accdb"
        connString = provider & dataFile
        myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
        myConnection.Open()
        Dim str As String
        str = "Insert into Items([ID No],[FirstName],[MiddleInitial],[LastName],[Birthdate]) Values (?,?,?,?,?)"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("ID No", CType(TextBoxIDno.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("FirstName", CType(TextBoxFN.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("MiddleInitial", CType(TextBoxMI.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("LastName", CType(TextBoxLN.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Birthdate", CType(TextBoxBD.Text, String)))
    End Sub
```

So what this code does is insert new data to the following columns in an access database, but I dont know how to make it insert data in a specific table in the database (the db has a couple tables)

I know that I have to insert this ("Select * FROM ~name of table~") code but I dont know where.

Sorry I'm a total newbie.

Comment: So, what is `Items` here? Are you executing the command somewhere? This code tries to insert data. `Select` is used to extract it. Did you write this code? Why are you converting a string to `string`?  Are some of those *strings* supposed to be some other type, maybe (as `TextBoxIDno.Text`, it looks like it should be numeric)? The Parameters type is missing. Where's `myConnection` coming from? Are you storing it? If so, don't.

Comment: `Insert into Items` says you are inserting the record into the `Items` table. if you want to insert into another table you need `Insert into [otherTableName]`

Comment: `So what this code does is insert new data to the following columns in an access database, but I don't know how to make it insert data in a specific table in the database`. Columns exist within a table, so by saying *this code inserts data into the following columns*, you are actually saying **this code inserts data into this table's columns** ...`Items` table in this case. Yet you follow up with, *but I don't know how to make it insert data into a specific table*. What exactly do you want to do because your code is already doing what you are asking. Specify another table name if needed.

Comment: I have no experience in visual basic whatsoever, this is for a school project, so the "Items" was what I was supposed to rename into the name of the table I need. Got it THANKS!